# Algolia Facet Filters with Array Value

Tags: filter, facet, algolia

For some reason, facet filters broke recently in algolia.  I have products that have array attributes such as "pa_size:["XS", "S", "M", "L", "XL"]". I added "_product_attributes.pa_size.value" to the Attributes for faceting and set it to "searchable".

But when I try adding a facet filter such as "pa_size:M" directly in the algolia explorer I get 0 rows returned.  It does the same thing with other similar facet filters.

Here's the raw query:

```
index.search("", {
  "getRankingInfo": 1,
  "facets": "*",
  "attributesToRetrieve": "*",
  "highlightPreTag": "<em>",
  "highlightPostTag": "</em>",
  "hitsPerPage": 10,
  "facetFilters": [
    "pa_size:M"
  ],
  "maxValuesPerFacet": 100
});
```

Here's the attribute:

```
"_product_attributes" : {
    "pa_size" : {
    "name" : "pa_size",
    "value" : "",
    "position" : "1",
    "is_visible" : 1,
    "is_variation" : 1,
    "is_taxonomy" : 1
},
```

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Rob

Comment: I found in the docs that

"If a filtered attribute contains an array of values, any matching value will cause the filter to match."

Answer (score 2):

It turned out to be a fairly simple issue.  The attributes needed to be added to the Attributes for faceting list, but I was having problems saving it.  That's why it didn't work.  Once I was able to save the "pa_size" attribute, it worked as expected.

[image]